# Sequelize one to many association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to map sequelize one to many association by referring to sequelize documentation but I could not able to find a complete example to get it work.

I have a *ClaimType* model as follows

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    const ClaimType = sequelize.define('claim_type', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    }, {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true
        });

    return ClaimType;
};
```

and *MaxClaimAmount*

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    const MaxClaimAmount = sequelize.define('max_claim_amount', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        amount: {
            type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
        },
        year: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }
    }, {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true
        });

    return MaxClaimAmount;
};
```

finally in *index.js*

```
const ClaimType = require('./model/claim_type.js')(sequelize);
const MaxClaimAmount = require('./model/max_claim_amount.js')(sequelize);
ClaimType.hasMany(MaxClaimAmount, { as: 'claimAmount' });

sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
            return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
                return ClaimType.create({
                    name: 'OPD'
                }, { transaction: t }).then(function (claimType) {            
                    // want to know how to associate MaxClaimAmount
                });
            }).then(function (result) {
                sequelize.close();
                console.log(result);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                sequelize.close();
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
```

*ClaimType* object is returned from the first part of the transaction and I want to know how to implement the association between *ClaimType* and *MaxClaimAmount*?

Answer (score 0):

You make the association in your models.

(Associations: one-to-many in sequelize docs)

```
const ClaimType = sequelize.define('claim_type', {/* ... */})

const MaxClaimAmount = sequelize.define('max_claim_type', {/* ... */})

ClaimType.hasMany(MaxClaimAmount, {as: 'MaxClaims'})
```

This will add the attribute `claim_typeId` or `claim_type_id` to `MaxClaimAmount` (you will see the column appear in your table). Instances of `ClaimType` will get the accessors `getMaxClaims` and `setMaxClaims` (so you can set foreign id on table)

The next step would be creating your backend routes and using the accessor instance methods to set a foreign key.  The accessor functions are called like so:  `(instance1).setMaxClaims(instance2)`

Instances are returned from queries